# How to split common definitions in ConfigParser?

Tags: python, configparser

I'm a big proponent of DRY and would like to split my `CFG` file into a common section and env-specific sections, and have the env-sections "inherit" from the common section, like so:

```
[generic]
basedir = ~/computational-services/jobs
pattern = Job*
usage-jar = ../lib/usage-logging-client.jar

[dev-test]
age = 7
dirs = [
     ('%(basedir)s/rundir01', %(age)s, '%(pattern)s', 'cleanupRunDir01'),
     ('%(basedir)s/linuxNonimmediate', %(age)s, '%(pattern)s', 'cleanupLinuxNonimmediate01'),
     ]

[prod]
age = 14
dirs = [
     ('%(basedir)s/rundir01', %(age)s, '%(pattern)s', 'cleanupRunDir01'),
     ]
```

Right now, I'm getting the following error:

```
ConfigParser.InterpolationMissingOptionError: Bad value substitution:
    section: [dev-test]
    option : dirs
    key    : basedir
    rawval : [
('%(basedir)s/rundir01', %(age)s, '%(pattern)s', 'cleanupRunDir01'),
('%(basedir)s/linuxNonimmediate', %(age)s, '%(pattern)s', 'cleanupLinuxNonimmediate01'),
]
```

If I do repeat myself, and add `basedir` and `pattern` to `[dev-test]` all is good:

```
[dev-test]
age = 7
basedir = ~/computational-services/jobs
pattern = Job*
dirs = [
     ('%(basedir)s/rundir01', %(age)s, '%(pattern)s', 'cleanupRunDir01'),
     ('%(basedir)s/linuxNonimmediate', %(age)s, '%(pattern)s', 'cleanupLinuxNonimmediate01'),
     ]
```

Is there a way to use a key/value from one section in another (even tried `generic.basedir` and `generic:basedir`)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, sorry, just checked the documentation again and read about `DEFAULT`:

```
[DEFAULT]
basedir = ~/computational-services/jobs
pattern = Job*
usage-jar = ../lib/usage-logging-client.jar

[dev-test]
age = 7
dirs = [
     ('%(basedir)s/rundir01', %(age)s, '%(pattern)s', 'cleanupRunDir01'),
     ('%(basedir)s/linuxNonimmediate', %(age)s, '%(pattern)s', 'cleanupLinuxNonimmediate01'),
     ]
```

Should spend as much time searching the documentation as checking SO. :)